# How to change the active configuration profile in gcloud?

Tags: google-compute-engine, gcloud, gcloud-cli

I have created a new configuration profile using command:

```
gcloud init
```

and now I don't know how to switch to old configuration profile without override it.

Using `gcloud config` I can't switch to another configuration only set a property of the current configuration.

any idea?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What do you mean by `can't only switch`?

Comment: @Grzenio `gcloud init propose` you 1) re-initialize current configuration. 2) create a new configuration, 3) switch to another existing configuration and re-initialize. but you can't switch without re-initialize. Thanks

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can see your configurations (created via gcloud init) via

```
gcloud config configurations list
```

You can switch to a different configuration via

```
gcloud config configurations activate MY_OLD_CONFIG
```

Once activated you can

```
gcloud config list
```

to see its settings.

You can also do this without activation by running

```
gcloud config list --configuration CONFIGURATION_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small Bash tool for anyone who needs to do this on a regular basis: https://github.com/uhinze/gconf

To list configs: `gconf`

To switch to a different config: `gconf <CONFIG>`

To then switch to the previous config (helpful when you're working with 2): `gconf -`